# How do I fix "ImportError: No module named index" when importing RTree in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, r-tree

I tried installing [Rtree 0.7.0](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/) from PyPI, but I keep getting `ImportError: No module named index` when I try to use it.  I downloaded and ran the Rtree-0.7.0.win32.exe from the [Downloads](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/#downloads) page, and everything appears to be installed properly.

Here's the full error message that I get (from the Python 3.2.2 shell):

```
>>> from rtree import index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from rtree import index
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\rtree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from index import Rtree
ImportError: No module named index

>>> import rtree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import rtree
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\rtree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from index import Rtree
ImportError: No module named index
```

The error message indicates that there's no module named 'index', but when I look in my `C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\rtree\` directory, I see that it's there.

[image: RTree Package Directory]

What could be causing me to still get the `ImportError: No module named index` error message, and how can I fix it so I can use the RTree module?

Comment: Can you open index.py and see if Rtree class is defined?

Comment: `RTree` is not Python 3 ready; relative imports don't work on Python 3.

Comment: @ATOzTOA There's an Index class defined, with an alias for RTree.

Comment: [`2to3` will fix this](http://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-import); you could give it a whirl and see if `RTree` works automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to rely on `import foo` doing a [relative import](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). It was the default behavior in 2.x (from 2.5 onwards there's a `__future__` directive overriding that). Python 3 [removed this](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax). So the maintainers probably didn't even try to be 3.x-compatible, and the installation just worked by chance. Appropriately, there is no claim of Python 3 compatibility: No `Programming Language :: Python :: 3` trove classifier, no mention in the documentation, no use of 2to3 in `setup.py`, etc. Short of patching `rtree` to fix this, and probably numerous other issues, you won't get it to work.

Comment: I guess I read too much in to **Py Version** = "any" on the downloads page.  It does appear to work when I run the installer for Python 2.7.2, so I guess I'll just make the rest of my code work in 2.7.  Thank you.